# How do I add a tab bar to the storyboard of an existing project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have used storyboard for the very fist time. The app is 80% complete by now and became slightly more complex than I thought originally. I think the user experience could be improved by using a tab view for the application and separate certain parts into tabs so that the user can easily switch between them. I am familiar with building tab bar apps programmatically and using IB classic (w/o storyboard) but I am currently a bit lost. How do I add a tab bar controller to the storyboard of an existing project?

Comment: It is probably quite easy but I just don't see it. My uncertainties circle around that the storyboard, as generated automatically when the project began, starts off with a navigation controller. Once the change is performed it should somehow start off with a tab bar controller and have an individual navigation controller for each (or most of) the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guide with code and screenshot [creating a uitabbarcontroller programmatically with storyboards](http://www.yacana.ro/creating-a-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-with-storyboards-aka-storyboarding-like-a-baws/) and this [Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5 Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

Comment: Thanks. As usual, Ray's tutorial gave the answer. It was the little bit of information that I missed. There is this "Initial Scene" property of the view controller that has to be set to "Is initial view controller" (ticked).